# What is probability-frequency function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What is probability-frequency function and how it differs from probability function?

Comment: May I ask, in what context did this question arise for you?

Comment: Image processing

Comment: "An iterative method of restoring degraded images was developed by treating images, point spread functions,
and degraded images as probability-frequency functions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you observe a random sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ from some discrete density $f$ and wish to estimate that density, one way is to note the frequencies of each occurrence of elements from the sample space $S$:

$$
  \hat{f}(x)
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{ X_i = x\}}.
$$ 
This estimate [converges a.s.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) to $f(x) = {\bf E}[1_{\{ X = x \}}]$. You are essentially building an [empirical distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function), which can also be done in the continuous setting by looking at something like 
$$
  \hat{F}(x)
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{ X_i \leq x\}}.
$$
However, the term "frequency" doesn't make much sense in the continuous setting since the probability of observing any fixed value $x$ is $0$.